# Unable to refresh a Google OAuth 2 token after update using 'Python Social Auth'

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, python-social-auth

I am using [Python Social Auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) in a [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) project and everything was working fine.

I have just updated Python social authentication to 0.2.1, and I am getting an error with load_strategy when trying to refresh a Google [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) 2 token.

Until now I was using:

```
strategy = load_strategy(backend='google-oauth2')
user = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(uid=..., provider="google-oauth2")
refresh_token(strategy=strategy, redirect_uri='http://.....')
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: load_strategy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'backend'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue after update.

Here is example from the docs:

It’s a common scenario that mobile applications will use an SDK to signup a user within the app, but that signup won’t be reflected by python-social-auth unless the corresponding database entries are created. In order to do so, it’s possible to create a view / route that creates those entries by a given access_token. Take the following code for instance (the code follows Django conventions, but versions for others frameworks can be implemented easily):

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

from social.apps.django_app.utils import psa

# Define an URL entry to point to this view, call it passing the
# access_token parameter like ?access_token=<token>. The URL entry must
# contain the backend, like this:
#
#   url(r'^register-by-token/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$',
#       'register_by_access_token')

@psa('social:complete')
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
    # This view expects an access_token GET parameter, if it's needed,
    # request.backend and request.strategy will be loaded with the current
    # backend and strategy.
    token = request.GET.get('access_token')
    user = request.backend.do_auth(request.GET.get('access_token'))
    if user:
        login(request, user)
        return 'OK'
    else:
        return 'ERROR'
```

Hope that helps

Comment: But your answer has nothing to do with my question.